# Svg não é renderizada, o browser faz o download do arquivo em iis

Tags: javascript, html, iis, svg

Ao acessar o site que contém uma imagem svg, ela não aparece mas o navegador faz o download da imagem e no console de debug aparece a seguinte mensagem:

**Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream:**

o servidor é da localweb e é iis, o site é desenvolvido em asp. 
no html está da seguinte maneira:

```
<object id="imgSvg" data="map.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
```

O que pode estar errado ?!

Answer (score 2):

Toda vez que o IIS recebe uma requisição, ele obtém o recurso (uma página, imagem etc.) requisitado e o devolve no canal HTTP. Imagine que a resposta do IIS é entregue ao navegador dentro de um "envelope", e que no cabeçalho desse envelope existem diversas informações extras além do que você pediu. Uma dessas informações é o tipo do conteúdo dentro do envelope.

O navegador usa essa informação para decidir como deve abrir o conteúdo. Se o IIS disser que uma imagem é uma página, o navegador vai tentar abrí-la como página, e vice-versa.

O que acontece no seu caso é que o IIS não sabe o que é SVG, então ele envia como o tipo padrão dele, que é aplicativo. Isso sempre força o download.

Para resolver, você precisa adicionar o tipo do SVG no dicionário de tipos MIME do IIS. Segue a documentação oficial sobre como fazer isso: [http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc725608(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

E para o caso de um dia o link quebrar:

> Abra o Gerenciador do IIS e navegue até o nível que deseja gerenciar. (...).
>
> - Em Exibição de Recursos, clique duas vezes em Tipos de MIME.
> - No painel Ações, clique em Adicionar.
> - Na caixa de diálogo Adicionar Tipo de MIME, digite uma extensão de nome de arquivo na caixa de texto Extensão de nome de arquivo. Por exemplo, digite .xyz.
> - Digite um tipo MIME na caixa de texto Tipo MIME. Digite, por exemplo, application/octet-stream.
> - Clique em OK.

Apenas substitua .xyz por .svg. E não use `application/octet-stream`, isso é o que força downloads. Ao invés disso use `image/svg+xml`.

Comment: eu adicionei usando a seguinte sintax:
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
</staticContent>

Comment: Sem alterar a configuração do IIS isso não adianta muito. O navegador olha primeiro o cabeçalho HTTP. Se o cabeçalho diz que o seu SVG é um aplicativo, então o navegador vai tratar como aplicativo e ignorar o que quer que você tenha escrito no markup.

Comment: Eu fiz essa alteração no iis :)

Comment: Ah, foi mal. Nunca fiz isso dessa forma antes e nem sabia que era possível (ou como chegar em uma tela que o permita).